# Convergence behaviour of an iteration of a square root using Halley's method.

Tags: numerical-methods, recurrence-relations, fixed-point-theorems

As a part of finding square roots, I am asked to use Halley's method on $f(x)=x^2-a$. Using this I derived the iteration formula:
$$ p_{n+1} =\frac{p_n^3 + 3a p_n}{3p_n^2 +a}$$
Now I am asked to investigate whether the convergence process converges to a unique fixed point $p$. As a hint I should consider the intitial point $p_0$ and the unique fixed point $p$. More precisely:

**Hint: consider the cases $p_0 > p$ and $0 < p_0 < p$ separately.**

I am not sure how to use this hint, I think it boils down to manipulating inequalities, but my problem is that I have an equation in terms of $p_n$ and not $p$ and $p_0$. I guess an assumption would be that if we get a fixed point then $p_{n+1}= p_n$. Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show that 
$$
q_{n+1}=\frac{p_{n+1}-\sqrt{a}}{p_{n+1}+\sqrt{a}}=\left(\frac{p_{n}-\sqrt{a}}{p_{n}+\sqrt{a}}\right)^3=q_n^3.
$$
The convergence behavior directly follows from $|q_0|=\left|\frac{p_{0}-\sqrt{a}}{p_{0}+\sqrt{a}}\right|<1$ for $p_0>0$, as then $$p_n=\frac{1+q_0^{3^n}}{1-q_0^{3^n}}\sqrt{a}.$$

Comment: Doesn't this still raise some minor question about whether $(p_n+\sqrt{a}) \left ( \frac{p_n - \sqrt{a}}{p_n + \sqrt{a}} \right )^3$ still goes to zero? Somehow you should show separately that $p_n$ is bounded, which I think is where their hint is helpful (certainly that hint is useful in Newton's method for the square root).

Comment: @Ian : You get $$\frac{p_n-\sqrt{a}}{p_n+\sqrt{a}}=q_0^{3^n},~~ |q_0|<1,$$ which can be solved to $$p_n=\frac{1+q_0^{3^n}}{1-q_0^{3^n}}\sqrt{a},$$ which clearly converges.

Comment: Fair enough, that works. Probably not exactly what the author of the question intended, but it works.

Comment: @Ian : Indeed. I first encountered the consideration of these fractions and the simplification they offer in proofs of the Newton-Kantorovich theorem, for instance in Ortega-Rheinboldt.

Comment: I don't quite understand how the object $$
\frac{p_{n+1}-\sqrt{a}}{p_{n+1}+\sqrt{a}}=\left(\frac{p_{n}-\sqrt{a}}{p_{n}+\sqrt{a}}\right)^3.
$$ tells me anything about convergence?

Comment: @WesleyStrik Once you check that $\left | \frac{p_0-\sqrt{a}}{p_0+\sqrt{a}} \right |<1$, it gives you convergence of the ratio $\frac{p_n-\sqrt{a}}{p_n+\sqrt{a}}$ to zero. Doing a little algebra like LutzL and I discussed in these comments gives you convergence of $p_n$ itself.

Comment: @WesleyStrik Right.

Comment: And I can also just prove this formula rather quickly by induction, perhaps (the final one by Lulz. I'll first give this some thought and wor kit out for myself. Thanks so far.

Comment: Probably not how the author meant the exercise to be solved, but I like this method.